# Google Play Services - Unity - Can only invite 'recent players' on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

When you create a game with invitation screen on iOS you only get to see the people who recently played your game. Is there anyway we can get to see all the people in your circles like in Android builds?

On Android you get the recent, active and all people in your circles.
[image: On Android you get the recent, active and all people in your circles.]

On iOS you get the recent players only
[image: On iOS you get the recent players only]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission model is subtly different on iOS vs. Android.  On iOS, only players that have logged in and played the game are shown (recent players).  On Android the Google Plus credentials are used to get Circle information.  At this time there is not an API to get Circle information on iOS.

Comment: Any update on this @ClaytonWilkinson?  Its not the best experience for players to see the recent players only?